# --max-old-space-size missing value in yarn / next

Tags: node.js, next.js, yarn-v2

Using *Windows*

When I run yarn build I get the following error:

```
{
  args: [
    'NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192',
    'next',
    'build',
    '--debug'
  ],
  env: { NODE_OPTIONS: '--max-old-space-size' },
  cmd: [ 'next', 'build', '--debug' ]
}
Error: missing value for flag --max-old-space-size of type size_t
Try --help for options
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe: bad option: --max-old-space-size
Note: This command was run via npm module 'win-node-env'
error Command failed with exit code 9.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command
```

Even though the value should be assigned as an environment variable, a snippet from my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
        "build": "yarn pre-build && NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192 next build --debug",
        "build:analyze": "yarn pre-build && NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192 BUNDLE_ANALYZE=true next build",
```

It appears to be treating this as a command instead of an environment variable. Is there a way to change this?

Comment: Try installing `cross-env` and modify the `build` script to: `"build": "yarn pre-build && cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--max-old-space-size=8192' next build --debug"`